# How should I define methods when using knockout.js?

Tags: javascript, oop, data-binding, methods, knockout.js

Various online object-oriented JavaScript tutorials seem to suggest that defining methods using traditional function syntax, such as:

```
function x(y) { ... }
```

is equivalent to:

```
x = function (y) { ... }
```

I've since discovered some differences - e.g. the point at which the function names are bound.

I was defining my methods using the traditional function syntax, but found that I couldn't create a "submit" binding in knockout.js. The following binding didn't work:

```
 <form id="myForm" action="#" method="get" data-bind="submit: x">
```

It reports:

```
Message: ReferenceError: x is not defined;
```

However, it *does* work when I use the non-traditional "assignment" function syntax.

Can anyone explain why I can't bind to a method that uses the traditional syntax?

If anyone knows of a comprehensive discussion of the differences between the different method syntaxes, that might be useful. It's a difficult subject to search on (at least when you're not sure of the official terminology).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean you wrote the first variant inside your View Model object like this:

```
var ViewModel = { 
    function x(y) { ... }
}
```

In this case this function is not a "property" of your View Model object and it cannot be bound via knockout.

But in the case you specify it as a part of your object, it can be bound:

```
var ViewModel = { 
    x(y): function { ... }
}
```

As i understand there is no difference between these two variants it you define a function in global scope (not related to any JS object)

Answer (score 0):

There is a big difference in javascript between using `function x(y) { ... }` and `x = function (y) { ... }`

especially if you define `this.x = function (y) { ... }` inside a function, you actually create a public method on your function (class in OO terminology).

Comment: Dommer asked what the difference is, and your answer repeats that there is a difference, but does not explain further the technicalities of the difference. Do you have references for the differences?